# Why message queues are in Kernel address space but not the shared memory

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, message-queue, shared-memory

I have been asked in an interview why the message queues are in kernel address space and same has been suggested in following link.

http://stork.sourceforge.net/thesis/node49.html

Which says "Message queue can be best described as an internal linked list within the kernel's addressing space".

I answered telling interviewer kernel logical addresses can't be swapped out and hence make message queue more robust in a situation where we have to retrieve some data from message queue after any process crash.

I am not sure this is right answer.

Also interviewer then asked why shared memory is not part of kernel address space ?

I couldn't really think of it why is it so.

Can anyone please address these two questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say message queues are maintained in kernel space for (a) historical reasons and (b) architectural reasons -- they are modeled as a kernel-managed resource: they are only created, modified, and deleted according to the defined API. That means, for example, once a process sends a message, it can't be modified in flight, it can only be received. Access controls are also imposed on objects in the queue. Managing and enforcing the details of the API would be difficult if it were maintained in user space memory.

That being said, apart from the security/assurance aspects, you probably could actually implement message queues with the same API *using* a shared memory area and have it be completely transparent to consuming applications.

For shared memory itself, the key is it's *shared*. That means in order to fulfill its function, it must be accessible in the virtual address spaces of process A and process B at the same time. If process A stores a byte at a given offset in the shared memory, process B should (ideally) see that modification near-instantaneously (though obviously there will always be a potential for cache delays and so forth in multi-processor systems). And user-space processes are never allowed to directly modify kernel virtual addresses so the shared mapping must be created in user virtual address space (though there's no reason the kernel could not *also* map the same region into kernel virtual address space).

Comment: Thanks Gil for the answer ,I am able to understand the point you made about shared memory but I am still not get the point you made about message queues, why maintaining messages queues are difficult in user space?Did you find my reason OK that kernel logical addresses can't be swapped out and hence make message queue more robust?

Comment: Creating message queues in user space isn't difficult at all, but making them follow the defined semantics as to ownership and access control would be. Note that a newly created message queue is owned by the EUID of the creating process and that permissions are associated with it. Providing and enforcing those permissions would be difficult in user space. I don't see how not being swapped out makes the queues any more robust (although it might have performance benefits).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike share-memory, message queue can be implemented in kernel space is because the content of each element of queue is just a COPY action between user space and kernel address space when transferring data between two user processes. Hence there is no any chance that user can destroy kernel memory space via memory pointer. It is similar to that Linux uses copy_to_user() and copy_from_user() to protect kernel from user's careless.